# error MSB4066: The attribute "Version" in element <PackageReference> is unrecognized. in teamcity

Tags: .net, nuget, teamcity, maui

I got this error and Im trying to deploy a build configuration of .NET maui desktop app in teamcity , this error was in the first build step of NuGet installer.
Here is some versions info :
the .Net version is 7 , the Msbuild in my local is 4.0 , NuGet version is 6.5.0 .

here is what I tried :
I add package resources : https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
I tried to change Msbuild version
and select the option of Update packages with help of NuGet update command .